# SQL query for Altering all the schemas present in a workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 schemas, each of which has its own number of tables, but I have one table common for all the schemas(ex: Student). Can anyone tell me SQL query on how to add a field to all the Student table present in all the schema's.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: best way is to do it one by one :) sorry :), otherwise you need to write complicated script generator which is unwise for 5 schemas

Comment: Why do you have the same table 5 times?

Comment: @jarlh in my project , there is a concept of Business Units, where many companies will be using the application at once and updating their information I need to write a migration script to add a field to a particular table present in all the schema's.

Comment: If you know all the schemas, why don't you write a 5 different query to insert to all the tables. I think this is the better approach.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty, it needs to be dynamic, the 5 schema's might not be fixed all the time, it might increase or decrease depending on the client.

Comment: for that you need to use the dynamic SQL then.